# High Availability Redis

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery

I have a django project which currently uses a redis cache both as my celery broker and as my regular cache. I like this setup because it solves 2 of my needs with 1 technology. However, recently I have been having trouble with redis crashes. The issue is that when redis goes down, my whole site ceases functioning because the tasks are extremely important.

So my question is, should I find another broker for my celery tasks, or is there a way I can get high availability out of redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "the tasks are extremely important" you should use [RabbitMQ](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html) broker instead of Redis.

Comment: Thats what we ended up moving to :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check [Redis Sentinel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) which is the official high availability solution for Redis (work in progress, actively developed though).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where your app is hosted at, you could use a hosted Redis provider that offers HA.

Comment: I work for Redis Labs and we offer  [Redis Cloud](http://redis-cloud.com) - a scalable, highly available hosted Redis service.